# Run Windows Terminal with non-executed predefined command

Tags: windows, powershell, command, powershell-cmdlet, windows-terminal

I need to run Windows Terminal with specific settings. I need it to start powershell in directory to `C:\dir` and type command `yarn start` to console input but not execute the command. **I just want to have this command prepared** and then I just press enter to execute the command when I am ready.
This is my actual solution which automaticaly executes the command:

```
wt -p "Windows Powershell" -d C:\dir powershell -noExit yarn start
```

**Edit:**
Is there any way to this feature work also with multiple panes?
Code provided by @mklement0 works only without panes and following code  does not work.

```
wt `
-p "Windows Powershell" -d C:\dir1 `; split-pane `
-p "Windows Powershell" -d C:\dir2 `; split-pane `
-p "Windows Powershell" -d C:\dir3 powershell -noExit -c @'
  (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).SendKeys('yarn start')
'@
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In order to have your `yarn start` command appear at the PowerShell prompt *without submitting it*, you'll have to *simulate user input*:

```sh
wt -p "Windows Powershell" -d C:\dir powershell -noExit -c @'
  (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).SendKeys('yarn start')
'@
```